# chart js 3 radar, how to enabe multiline labels

Tags: javascript, webpack, chart.js, radar-chart

I'm using chart js 3 to draw a radar graph .

I'm getting labels text from backend .

I'm trying to make labels responsive and apply multilines and wrap words .

My current config is :

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "radar",
        data: {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [
          ...
```

I added a liste of options to make graph responsive and to give a custom style :

```
options: {
          scales: {
            r: {
              pointLabels: {
                font: {
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontFamily: "Roboto",
                },
              },
            },
          },
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          responsive: true,
          layout: {
            padding: 0,
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          plugins: {
            title: {
              display: false,
              text: "Les évaluations",
            },
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
        },
```

I'm getting this graph :

[image]

> I can't find and options to enable multlines labels or to apply wrap to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your variable `labels` is an array containing strings in this way: `["Je note la qualité du pitch...", "Je donne ma voix pour sélectionner cette startup, sous réserve"]`

What you have to do is to make a 2D Array containing your same sentences but splitted in sub array like that : `[["Je note la qualité", "du pitch..."], ["Je donne ma voix", "pour sélectionner", "cette startup, sous réserve"]]`

By doing this, you should have multi lines sentences, to break your string into multiple strings (chunks), here is a quick implementation :
`const newLabels = labels.map(l => l.match(/.{1,n}/g))` where n is your max length per line.

If you want to split your string by number of words, try this chunking implementation :

```
const splitString = (text, chunkSize) => {
    const arr = text.split(" ")
    const output = []

    for (let i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i += chunkSize) {
        output.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize))
    }

    return output
}

console.log(splitString("Hi this is a sample string that I would like to break down into an array!", 3))
```

You should obtain this :

```
[
  [ 'Hi', 'this', 'is' ],
  [ 'a', 'sample', 'string' ],
  [ 'that', 'I', 'would' ],
  [ 'like', 'to', 'break' ],
  [ 'down', 'into', 'an' ],
  [ 'array!' ]
]
```

Comment: thank you so much, can i match number of words instead of number of caracters ?

Comment: with pleasure ! I edited my answer, take a look :)

Answer (score 2):

You can define the `labels` as an array of string arrays.

> This is described in the Chart.js documentation under [Data Structures](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#data-structures) as follows: *"In case you want multiline labels you can provide an array with each line as one entry in the array."*

Please take a look at the runnable code snippet below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: [['Deep', 'Red'], ['Nice', 'Blue'], ['Cute', 'Yellow']],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [300, 250, 280],
      borderColor: '#FF6384'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
```