# Chart.js (React) I need to put the labels like a paragraph, I don't want rotate labels

Tags: reactjs, charts, rotation, chart.js, label

I using React with char.js my labels rotating 45o, But I don't want it

[image]

I need the labels in this mode similar a paragraph, the text in the overflow get down, like a ,
[image]

I tried to use:

```
maxRotation: 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chart js 3 radar, how to enabe multiline labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70532249/chart-js-3-radar-how-to-enabe-multiline-labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels can be multi-lines, defining each label as an array of strings:

```
  labels: [['En diàlogos cotidianos', 'con', 'empleados'], 
           ['En medios de', 'comunicaciòn'], 
           ['En campanas', 'o eventos'], 
           'No'],
```

See below the snippet.

```js
 const data = {
      labels: [['En diàlogos cotidianos', 'con', 'empleados'], 
               ['En medios de', 'comunicaciòn'], 
               ['En campanas', 'o eventos'], 
               'No'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Sales',
        data: [10000, 20000, 30000,40000],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        borderWidth: 0
      },{

        label: 'Target',
        data: [50000, 50000, 50000, 40000,],
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        borderWidth: 0
      }]
    };

    // config
 const config1 = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          x: {
            stacked: true
          },
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            stacked: true
          }
        }
      },
    };

    new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config1
    );
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```